# how can i loop for store items i want in ExtJS XTemplate?

Tags: extjs, model, store

i have store which contains all data about items. also it contains data which can have multiple values.
i have been searching for hours and couldn't find answer. maybe i'm searching wrong way or for wrong solution for this problem.
so can i group them or something like this so i can loop through data i want???:

```
parents: [
  {name: 'parentName', type: 'string'},
  {name: 'parentLastName', type: 'string'},
  {name: 'parentAge', type: 'number'}
]

children: [
  {name: 'childName', type: 'string'},
  {name: 'childLastName', type: 'string'},
  {name: 'childAge', type: 'number'},
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question could do with some more detail. Normally you would load data into your store via a proxy and access it via StoreManager. So if your store contains records, you could loop through them like this:

```
var store = Ext.data.StoreManager.lookup('<my store ID>');
// don't forget to store.load(); if autoload is false
store.each(function(record,id){
    // Do something with each record
    console.log(record);
});
```

To get a field from the record you could do, for example:

```
record.get('parentName');
```

Hope this helps. If not, please provide more info

Tim